# Symfony multiple form on one page

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm learning **symfony** and doing my first test project. I have a page with a list of upcoming events

```
(Entity - event (id, city, date, info))
```

And wanna add to each event a form to save a new client to event. How can I do this? I have add a client entity and **many-to-many** relations with Event entity, what should be next? how should look my form class?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your template, by default the FormType for your relation between Event and Client will be :

- `EntityType` with the `multiple` option to `true` in order to have checkboxes or a select box with mutliple selection
- `CollectionType` with an EntityType inside. This will create a separate field by client

These solutions will retrieve all your clients for each field(s) and can cause performance issues. So the best solution will be to create a [custom form type](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html) with an autocomplete field. You can start with a ChoiceType with an autocomplete javascript plugin and simple parameters (like the id and the name of the client) and finish by use a [data transformer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html) in order to retrieve Clients instead of names.

If your list of upcoming event is small you can create this form for each events. Otherwise you will have to do it differently :

1. Create just one form with a Collection of Events, read-only fields to display informations and the field to add Clients. This is the simpliest solution, I think.
2. Add dynamically your form for each event : You can do this using `render controller` feature but if you have a lot of events this will cause also performance issues. So the best solution will be to add these forms using AJAX calls or change your template :).